# iOS: Storing cookie that expires on session

Tags: ios, objective-c, nshttpcookie, nshttpcookiestorage

I have to set NSHTTPCookie such that it expiry is set to **Session**. I used the following code to set properties of that cookie.

```
NSMutableDictionary *cookieProperties = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[cookieProperties setObject:@"mycookiename" forKey:NSHTTPCookieName];
[cookieProperties setObject:@"mycookievalue" forKey:NSHTTPCookieValue];
[cookieProperties setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:TRUE] forKey:NSHTTPCookieSecure];
[cookieProperties setObject:@"com.mydomain" forKey:NSHTTPCookieDomain];
[cookieProperties setObject:@"com.mydomain" forKey:NSHTTPCookieOriginURL];
[cookieProperties setObject:@"/" forKey:NSHTTPCookiePath];
[cookieProperties setObject:@"0" forKey:NSHTTPCookieVersion];

NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:cookieProperties];
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:cookie];
```

However both of the above properties set the expiry to **1 Jan 2001 02:00:00 GMT+2** rather than setting the expiry to **Session**

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at **sessionOnly** property. 
[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookie_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSHTTPCookie/sessionOnly)

It says:

> A boolean value that indicates whether the receiver should be discarded at the end of the session (regardless of expiration date). (read-only)
>
> YES if the receiver should be discarded at the end of the session
>   (regardless of expiration date), otherwise NO.

You can also have a look at the superb library [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)

It has some nice methods that can help you. From their How-To:

> In this case, ‘session cookies’ refers to ALL cookies created during a session, rather cookies with no expiry date (often referred to as session cookies) that are removed when the application quits.

So you might want to create a `NSHTTPCookie` with no expiration date set.

This information can also be found in the **Apple Docs:**

> The receiver’s expiration date, or nil if there is no specific expiration date such as in the case of “session-only” cookies. The expiration date is the date when the cookie should be deleted.

To do so:

```
NSDictionary *properties = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
[properties setValue:[@"Test Value" encodedCookieValue] forKey:NSHTTPCookieValue];
[properties setValue:@"ASIHTTPRequestTestCookie" forKey:NSHTTPCookieName];
[properties setValue:@".allseeing-i.com" forKey:NSHTTPCookieDomain];

//Here you can set expiration date
[properties setValue:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60*60] forKey:NSHTTPCookieExpires];      
[properties setValue:@"/asi-http-request/tests" forKey:NSHTTPCookiePath];
NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [[[NSHTTPCookie alloc] initWithProperties:properties] autorelease];
```

Comment: i know that property but I want to construct NSHTTPCookie with sessionOnly property = TRUE

Comment: I tried that too but it doesn't chaneg result, see my edited question

Comment: what if you set the property explicitly to nil ?

Comment: you can't set nil to object in dictionary but I tried [NSNull null] and still the date is 1 Jan 2001 02:00:00 GMT+2

Comment: Sorry that it is not working for you. Maybe it has something to do with `NSHTTPCookieDiscard`. You could try setting it explicitly to true.